# Error: page.setRequestInterception is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, accessibility, pa11y

I could not set viewport with pa11y.I'm getting Error.

```
{
"defaults": {
    "timeout": 1000,
    "page": {
        "viewport": {
            "width": 320,
            "height": 480
        }
    }
},
"urls": [
    "https://sonymobile.com/gb",
    "https://sonymobile.com/gb/products/phone"
]
```

}

Some details are here :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "timeout": 1000 and try it again. I think the timeout passes and the page object is not set.